# Is my employer making my job unnecessarily hard or assigning useless work that helps nobody?

Tags: management, bullying

My employer said that they wanted me to copy and paste and itemize all the things in invoices part of a contract we receive and copy into excel. I can't just list the total amount of an invoice, I have to copy every word in it (per item) and separate by item into cells, separate all the dollar amounts by item, link it to the original file. Totally unrelated to generating the books for doing taxes. They told me this makes it easier for them to tell me which items to cross-out and not pay, and which items to pay, and is the only way to present to investors/owners.

They could have just looked at the invoice themselves and told me what we will not and will pay rather than having me do all the copying and having them tell me in a meeting what we won't pay.  and the investors could have just been sent a contract of what we agreed to pay rather than having me copy everything and re-invent the wheel. If they're too busy or lazy to read the invoices themselves and cross out what's unreasonable, that's their problem.

I'm sure the owners/investors have better things to do than micromanage every $100 we spend, and the only thing this might do is show on an itemized level what we spend, and de-aggregates everything.But wait, Invoices do that already!

As someone who knows databases, they want me to generate denormalized databases without a primary key, repeat a lot of things and make a bunch of bad database practices.

They also want me to copy and paste into excel all routine internet fees which have been the same thing every month, so I basically write month 1, $xxx.yy, month 2 $xxx.yy 50 times but that's useless as I could have told them multiply the time in months we've been running by $xxx.yy.

This is extra work on top of making the balance sheets of all previous years expenses, so it's not like we don't have books.

At a useful company such as Google, none of these things would help me be promoted.
There's no impact, no originality, no creativeness, no People Impact.
It's just an excuse to make me hate my job more.

Comment: What is your role at this company?

Comment: Executive Assistant but they tried to make me sound more intelligent/relevant by calling me a manager.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a rant

Comment: If by "copy every word in it" you mean type it out yourself, you can save yourself some pain by scanning it and using OCR in Adobe Acrobat DC to copy-paste text. From there you could even also develop a program to actually do it for you if you've got some coding knowledge and time.

Comment: Why don't you take this up as a useful challenge and try to automate the process where you can? Not only will you pick up new skills, you will also free up time to propose and work on projects that are interesting to you (bonus: it also shows initiative)

Answer (score 6):

Rule 1: not everyone thinks like you. Not everyone finds certain things easy. Some people value familiar formats or layouts more than you do.

Rule 2: once an owner has decided "I need a list of [whatever] in [this format]" they will get that list. The only question that remains is who will make it.

Rule 3: if a piece of work is boring, repetitive, and unpleasant it will get delegated as far down the company as it will go.

These three rules add up to this: you can't tell your boss to do it themselves, or to otherwise pass along your rejection of the task up the chain. You can suggest easier ways for you to do it (some sort of automation) though probably nobody cares enough about sparing you the effort to fund that work.

Oh and Rule 4: while some bosses assign you tasks to help you grow, learn, and get promoted, not all tasks you are assigned will meet that bar. Sometimes things just need to get done. If not you, who?

Comment: Rule 5: if you know databases, why not use that knowledge to automate these tasks, so scripts are doing the cutting and pasting?

Comment: SqL/noSQL expertise is not the same thing as optical character recognition. SQL is more like knowing how to find anything in a database and knowing how makes databases run fast.

Comment: @Germania You've just argued in favor of why a human needs to be involved in this process. That human just happens to be you, as designated by someone who gets to decide that it is up to you to do this.

Answer (score 5):

One of the principles of "Dev Ops" is to automate boring and mundane tasks.  The reason this has to be stated as a principle is that boring and mundane tasks are common at all levels in the work force.

This work sucks, I agree, but that is what your managers want.  So you have a choice, do what they ask or not.  The "or not" will probably involve you finding new employment.

You could attempt to automate some of this process by cutting and pasting the entire invoice into a text editor.  Then using some tool to modify that output so that it is in an excel or even a csv format.  That would make the work challenging and somewhat interesting.

Comment: And, if you succeed in that task you can finish work that would normally take several hours in a few minutes and coast/do continuous learning the rest of the day.

Comment: I have found C, AWK, and Common LISP to be a VERY powerful combination for doing things like this.  Use C code to do character-level fixes, use AWK to push things into LISP S-expressions, and use Common LISP for the heavy lifting.  When it is all over, dump a delimited file into Excel.  Of course, you have to start by knowing (about) C, AWK, and Common LISP...  KEY CONCEPT: DON'T try to do it all in ONE script in ONE language!

Answer (score 3):

The work is useful, but not *to you*

Red flag #1 is that you are an executive assistant with the title of "manager", but basically doing work that most companies will try to pawn off to interns.  Huuuh, what?  That's quite a misalignment there.

On the other hand, you have database skills.  [You are smarter, in some aspects, than your boss](https://www.educba.com/11-signs-youre-too-smart-for-your-job/).  This is a dead-end job for you.  If you can't change jobs, there is a wealth of information online for people who've been in the same situation as you.  Ultimately in order to stay, you'll have to humble yourself and up your coping skills.

If you can change jobs to a situation where your skills can be utilized and appreciated, that'd be best.  You'll need to be more discerning with taking jobs with sketchy titles that don't match the work.  Ask more questions.  Be more objective.

Kudos for working hard and paying your bills (smile)

Answer (score 2):

> Is my employer making my job unnecessarily hard or assigning useless work that helps nobody?

At any company that you work for, from time to time you will be asked to do work that is more difficult than what you are accustomed to or work that from your point of view adds no value to the company or anyone at the company.

You can either do the work as asked or refuse.  Refusing will likely have a negative impact on your future with that company.  If such requests become more common and you find yourself doing less of what you thought you would be doing and more of this other type of work then you should probably start looking for a new company to work for that is more in line with your expectations of work that you are capable/willing to do.